# Match a string as long as it doesn't appear within another string

Tags: regex, matlab

## Short Question

Is it possible to use  regular expressions to match a string which doesn't appear within some other longer string? (I'm using MATLAB)

### Example

```
shortString = {'hello', 'there'};
longString = {'why hello there', 'hello, my friend', 'hello and goodbye'};
wholeString = ['"why hello there", said one guy. The other guy over ' ...
'there said hello, my friend. hello and goodbye, said the ' ...
'third guy. So let''s all say hello!'];
```

In this example, I would like to match the elements of `shortString` in `wholeString`, as long as they do not appear in `wholeString` as a substring of an element of `longString`.

In the above example, I would only like to match the `'hello'` from `'So let''s all say hello!'`, and the `'there'` from `'The other guy over there'`.

## Specific Problem

I am writing a function that will markup the help comments at the top of a function to get it ready to be published using MATLAB's `publish` function (See [Publishing Markup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/marking-up-matlab-comments-for-publishing.html)). In addition to marking up the syntax of the function, I want to markup any inputs/outputs of the function, which appear outside of the syntax. Assume that I've extracted the help comments from the function in some way. Here are some example comments.

```
% SYNTAX
%    x = somefunction(y)
%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)
%
% DESCRIPTION
%    x = somefunction(y) does something to y and returns x. I also dont wan't
%       your answer to match the 'y' in 'your' or ''y''.
%
%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2) does something else with in1 and 
%       in2. Then it returns out1 and out2.
```

After marking up these comments with my current method, I have the following

```
%% Syntax
%        x = somefunction(y)
%        [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)
%
%% Description
% |x = somefunction(y)| does something to y and returns x. I also dont wan't
% your answer to match the 'y' in your or ''y''.
%
% |[out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)| does something else with in1 and 
% in2. Then it returns out1 and out2.
```

I would like to make each input and output argument appear mono-spaced in the Description section. I'd like the final text to be

```
%% Syntax
%        x = somefunction(y)
%        [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)
%
%% Description
% |x = somefunction(y)| does something to |y| and returns |x|. I also dont wan't
% your answer to match the 'y' in 'your', or ''y''.
%
% |[out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)| does something else with |in1| and 
% |in2|. Then it returns |out1| and |out2|.
```

The problem is that I can't just match the input arguments, or I would also match them in the syntax part that's already mono-spaced.

At my disposal is a cell-array containing each syntax definition, a cell-array containing each input argument, and a cell array containing each output argument.

```
syntax = {'x = somefunction(y)', '[out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)'};
inputs = {'y', 'in1', 'in2'};
outputs = {'x', 'out1', 'out2'};
```

Comment: To answer the problem of syntax matching, you can capture only the help text with `txt = help('yourfunction')`. Does this solve your issue completely?

Comment: @OlegKomarov Thanks, but no. The problem is not getting the help text, but marking it up. I want to mark it up so that I can publish it to html using the `publish` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit ad hoc, and I think it might be improved but suppose your input is:

```
txt = ['% SYNTAX' char(13)...
'%    x = somefunction(y)' char(13)...
'%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)' char(13)...
'%' char(13)...
'% DESCRIPTION' char(13)...
'%    x = somefunction(y) does something to y and returns x. I also dont wan''t' char(13)...
'%       your answer to match the ''y'' in ''your'' or ''''y''''.' char(13)...
'%' char(13)...
'%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2) does something else with in1 and ' char(13)...
'%       in2. Then it returns out1 and out2.'];

inout  = {'y', 'in1', 'in2', 'x', 'out1', 'out2'}';
```

Using regular expressions with look-ahead and look-behind operators, i.e. your `inputs` and `outputs` should be enclosed within `\s,\.\!\?;:%` AND be preceded AND followed by alphanumeric characters, OR be at the beginning (useless?) or end of the text:

```
expr = strcat('(?<=\w[\s,\.\!\?;:%]+|^)', inout,'(?=[\s,\.\!\?;:]+\w|\.?$)');
regexprep(txt,expr,'|$&|')
```

The result is:

```
ans =
% SYNTAX
%    x = somefunction(y)
%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2)
%
% DESCRIPTION
%    x = somefunction(y) does something to |y| and returns |x|. I also dont wan't
%       your answer to match the 'y' in 'your' or ''y''.
%
%    [out1, out2] = somefunction(in1, in2) does something else with |in1| and 
%       |in2|. Then it returns |out1| and |out2|.
```

### Alternatively

In a few steps, you can match `start` and `end` positions of your `syntax`, then retrieve positions of `inputs/outputs` and exclude those from the replace operation which are within `start/pos`.

Comment: Thanks! I like both solutions, but I implemented the alternative, because it was more flexible.